# Como solucionar ValueError PYTHON

Tags: python, string, input, int

Cuando pido ingresar un valor entero con el int(input), y el usuario ingresa un string, la consola da error, y quisiera saber como solucionarlo, para volverle a pedir al usuario, a través de un bucle, que ingrese un valor de tipo entero para continuar.

Answer (score 1):

Para poder pedir al usuario que ingrese un valor hasta que introduzca una respuesta válida se debe [manejar la excepción](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=try%20and%20except#handling-exceptions) `ValueError`  con un bloque `try / except` utilizando `input` dentro de un bucle `while` de la siguiente manera

```
while True:
    try:
        respuesta = int(input("Ingrese un número entero: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No es un número entero.")
if respuesta % 2 == 0:
    print("El número es par")
else:
    print("El número es impar")
```

Puedes encontrar aquí otros ejemplos https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/1436666 en la versión en inglés de Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la conversion que realizas. Por defecto la funcion `input` te devolvera un string asi le digites un numero. Puedes hacer las siguientes pruebas:

```
variable_1 = input('Ingresa el numero 23: ') #digitas el numero 23
print(type(variable_1)) # El resultado es <class 'str'>
variable_2 = input("Ingresa el texto 'hola mundo': ") # escribes "hola mundo"
print(type(variable_2)) # El resultado es <class 'str'>
```

Estas lineas no te van a generar error. Tu error proviene cuando haces la conversion de manera forzada. El resultado de `int('Hola Mundo')` obviamente te generara un error porque no es posible convertir a algun numero ese valor `Hola Mundo`.

La forma mas "pythonista" de pedirle a un usuario que ingrese un valor entero es de la siguiente forma:

```
s = ''
while not s.isdigit():
    s = input('Debe ingresar un entero: ')
s = int(s) #Esta sentencia jamas fallara, pues 's' ya es un string de un entero.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que el valor de "s" en tu código, lo necesito en formato int para asignarselo a una posición dentro de una variable, ya que si ingreso el numero en formato string, no puedo asignarselo a una matriz

Comment: @EmiValle En ese caso, saliendo del bucle `while` basta con poner `s = int(s)`. esta sentencia ya no dara error porque para poder ejecutarla se debe salir del `while`, y para salir del while se debe ingresar un entero correctamente. Ya he editaco el coddigo segun tu observacion

Comment: Gracias, sos un genio!